# Using MVC 5 How to change textbox to checkbox

Tags: checkbox, view

How to change the code below in the View from a textbox to now display a check box

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.status, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.status)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.status)
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The EditorFor (and Html.CheckBoxFor) expect a bool value to create a checkbox. So you must either convert your Status property to a bool